# Usage of html5 <input type="month"> for different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create an input field which lets the user select a month and a year. HTML5 introduced the input type "month" which suits my problem. It works fine in Chrome, Opera and Edge (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month).

If the user is using Firefox (or IE or any older Browser version), the input field doesn't show a date picker but instead expects a plain text input.

How can I implement my form in a way, that if the current browser supports input type="month", it shows the native browser datepicker, and if that's not the case, it shows a custom date picker? I expect the input type="month" to work in future Firefox versions and would like to automaticly use that functionality once it exists.

What would be the best way to implement a custom date picker?

I'm already using JQuery in my project. Furthermore I'm using Laravel, although I don't think that Laravel offers any utily in that regard.

Comment: Why don't you just show a custom datepicker for all browsers and maintain a consistent design throughout multiple browsers?

Comment: [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month#Handling_browser_support) from there and below explains it quite well

Comment: @Shuvojit true.... Instead of using the browser specific functionality for datepicker use JqueyUI date picker. as you are already using the jquery

Answer (score 0):

Yes HTML5 elements are not supported on the old browsers. You can't expect new technologies to work on old systems. :)

So as you already know you can use a custom date picker. And I will recommend http://www.daterangepicker.com/, as I have been using it for some time now.Pretty stable.

Not recommending jQueryUI datepicker anymore, as it come with lot of other stuff as a bulk and it will slowdown your app loading time.

Give shot to daterangepicker it will solve your issue. ;)